# How do I setup Sendmail and the FQDN for use with server images

Tags: ubuntu, sendmail, hostname, hosts, images

I have loadbalancer sitting infront of serveral webservers.

The website served up has a contact form that uses sendmail.

I have installed sendmail on one of these webservers: `web-01` This is the `hostname` of the machine.

I have gone into the `/etc/hosts` file and added the following:

`127.0.0.1 example.com web-01`

At this point the form is sending correctly from this machine.

Now, I want to create an image of this server, so I can create new servers from the image and place them behind the loadbalancer.

The problem is, when I create `web-02` from the `web-01-image` the `/etc/hosts` file still contains:

`127.0.0.1 example.com web-01`

There is no alias mapping `web-02` to `example.com` and sendmail does not have a valid `FQDN`. At this point I need to edit the `/etc/hosts` file every time I create a new server.

Is there a better approach to this?

Comment: Yes, it's called configuration management. Look into solutions like Ansible, Puppet, Chef, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use `MASQUERADE_AS` in sendmail.mc.

See file `cf/README` in sendmail distribution, section  [MASQUERADING AND RELAYING](https://www.sendmail.org/~ca/email/doc8.12/cf/m4/masquerading_relaying.html)